# Kotlin polymorphic serialization (string array and object array)

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, polymorphism

I have a server response that could return either an array of strings, or an array of objects, but I don't know how to define this polymorphic relationship. Here's the Kotlin code for the serializers. The `sentence` class needs to be a plain array, but the serializer needs a `val` key.

```
@Serializable
data class QuizResponse(
    val name: String,
    val quiz: List<Quiz>
)

@Serializable
data class Quiz(
    val id: Int,
    val question: String,
    val quiz_type: String,
    val video: BasicVideo,
    val answers: List<Answer>
)

@Polymorphic
@Serializable
sealed class Answer {

    @Serializable
    data class Sentence(val answer: List<String>) : Answer()

    @Serializable
    data class Choice(val answer: String, val id: Int, val is_correct: Boolean) : Answer()
}
```

Here's two example responses:

```
{
  "name":"STRING",
  "quiz":[
    {
      "id":123,
      "video":{
        "id":12,
        "name":"ABC"
      },
      "question": "Question text",
      "answers": ["a","b","c","d","e","f"],
      "quiz_type":"sentence"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name":"STRING",
  "quiz":[
    {
      "id":123,
      "video":{
        "id":12,
        "name":"ABC"
      },
      "question": "Question text",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "text": "abc",
          "is_correct": false,
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "text": "abc",
          "is_correct": true,
        },
      ],
      "quiz_type":"choice"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `answers` key can be an array of strings or an array of objects. This is dependent on the `quiz_type` key.

What's the correct approach to create a custom serializer for this data?

Comment: can do something like this `if(answers is Array<String?>)`

Comment: Don't make `Answer` a sealed class. I'd make it a regular data class with id having the default value of -1 and false for is_correct. Then write a custom retrofit adapter to handle the array of strings and array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is quite outdated, but for someone who is still looking for the answer:

You can use `quiz_type` as a polymorphic discriminator. You can learn about it [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator-for-polymorphism) and [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#custom-subclass-serial-name).

The solution should look similar to this:

```
@JsonClassDiscriminator("quiz_type")
sealed interface Quiz {
    
    @SerialName("sentence") // value of the discriminator
    data class Sentence(
        ...
        answers: List<String>
    ) 

    @SerialName("choice") // value of the discriminator
    data class Choice(
        ...
        answers: List<Answer>
    ) {
        data class Answer(...)
    }
}
```

If case you don't have a discriminator field in all models, you can select a serializer based on json content in runtime using [`JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-content-polymorphic-serializer/)